# How to write implementation while scrolling to the top using recyclerView and PagedListAdapter?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack, pagedlist

I used Android Jetpack components to develop my chat app, I want to add support for pagination in my chat log screen cause its took too time when get data from my data source and render messages in RecyclerView, all tutorials talk about bottom pagination and its work well with my other screen like contact, but i didn't found any implementation for top pagination, and i tried to write my implementation using `PagedList.BoundaryCallback` but it didn't work.

this my code:

```
  @MainThread
    override fun onZeroItemsLoaded() {
        super.onZeroItemsLoaded()
        Log.d(MessageBoundaryCallback::class.java.simpleName, "onZeroItemsLoaded()")
        helper.runIfNotRunning(PagingRequestHelper.RequestType.INITIAL) {
            val db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
            db.collection(Constants.FIRE_STORE_MESSAGES_COLLECTION_NAME)
                    .whereEqualTo(Constants.CHAT_ID, chatId)
                    .orderBy(Constants.MESSAGE_TIME, Query.Direction.DESCENDING)
                    .limit(pageSize)
                    .get().addOnCompleteListener(createMessageCallback(it))
        }
    }

   override fun onItemAtFrontLoaded(itemAtFront: Message) {
        super.onItemAtEndLoaded(itemAtFront)
        Log.d(MessageBoundaryCallback::class.java.simpleName, "onItemAtEndLoaded($itemAtFront: Message)")
        helper.runIfNotRunning(PagingRequestHelper.RequestType.BEFORE) {
            val db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
            db.collection(Constants.FIRE_STORE_MESSAGES_COLLECTION_NAME)
                    .whereEqualTo(Constants.CHAT_ID, chatId)
                    .whereLessThan(Constants.MESSAGE_TIME, itemAtFront.time)
                    .orderBy(Constants.MESSAGE_TIME, Query.Direction.DESCENDING)
                    .limit(pageSize)
                    .get().addOnCompleteListener(createMessageCallback(it))
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Just revers my layout manger

```
layoutManager.reverseLayout = true
```

And everything work like a charm